# Student, Faculty, Staff Directory in Java

Tags: java

I am just getting into Java and I have a project due for my class soon and keep running into the same error.  I am to create a student, faculty, staff directory that can add new entries, update them, and print them using the to String() method.  I was recommended to use a treeMap collection also.  The error involves the .getKey() method and being unable to find it.  I will include my code and would greatly appreciate any input to help me figure this out.  Thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Write a description of class Persons here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Directory {

    private String firstName, lastName;

    private TreeMap<String, Persons> schoolDirectory;
    private int numberInDirectory;

    public Directory() {
        schoolDirectory = new TreeMap<String, Persons>();

    }

    public String getKey() {
        return lastName + firstName;
    }

    public void addPerson(Persons newPersons) {
        schoolDirectory.put(Persons.getKey(), newPersons);
        numberInDirectory++;
    }

    public void addPerson(Staff newStaff) {
        schoolDirectory.put(newStaff.getKey(), newStaff);
        numberInDirectory++;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return numberInDirectory;
    }

    public class Persons {

        // instance variables - replace the example below with your own

        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String email;

    }
}

/**
 * Write a description of class People here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class People extends Directory {

    private String firstName, lastName, emailAddress, phoneNumber, ID;

    public People(String firstName, String lastName, String emailAddress, String phoneNumber, String ID) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return lastName + firstName;
    }
}

/**
 * Write a description of class Students here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Students extends People {

    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own

    private String classlevel;
    private int SudentID;

}

/**
 * Write a description of class Faculty here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Faculty extends People {

    private String RoomNumber;
    private String EmployeeStatus;
    private String ProgramOfInstruction;

    public Faculty(String firstName, String lastName, String emailAddress, String phoneNumber, String ID, String room, String status, String instruction) {
        super(firstName, lastName, emailAddress, phoneNumber, ID);
        RoomNumber = room;
        EmployeeStatus = status;
        ProgramOfInstruction = instruction;
    }
}

/**
 * Write a description of class Staff here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Staff extends People {

    private String OfficeNumber;
    private String JobTitle;

    public Staff(String firstName, String lastName, String emailAddress, String phoneNumber, String ID, String office, String position) {
        super(firstName, lastName, emailAddress, phoneNumber, ID);
        OfficeNumber = office;
        JobTitle = position;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the *exact* error message you get?

Comment: cannot find symbol - method getKey()

Comment: You have posted _way_ too much code. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) It'd also be handy to point to where you're getting this error.

Comment: Where in this mess of code does this error occur?

Comment: My fault, I figured itd be easier to post everything.  This is it:

Comment: schoolDirectory.put(Persons.getKey(), newPersons);

Comment: @user3758442 change it to schoolDirectory.put(newPersons.getKey(), newPersons);

Comment: I think you have your class hierarchy all confused, I'd consider revisiting it ;)

Comment: Do you want to be able to list the individual types (student, faculty, staff)?  Is there any relationship between them?

Comment: @kpo no luck with that

Comment: Yes @ MadProgrammer, I need to be able to add a person, print a list alphabetically, remove and retrieve a person.

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are probably right about my confusion :-P  I am new to this though and still learning.

Comment: @user3758442 But, do you want to identify the type of person, ie, list all the stuff members, list all the students by facility?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes sir and be able to add one

Answer (score 0):

First of all change:

```
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
```

to just:

```
import java.util.*
```

(this is just to keep things tidy)

then I would recommend using a Map or HashMap instead of a treeMap (However I am unfamiliar with treeMap)

EDIT: just change `Persons.getKey()` to `newPersons.getKey()`

You were trying to call it statically.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This would make the key non-unique, meaning that whatever you add to the directory would be overridden with this key